# Ethereum Mocha Terminal Error - "Error: Cannot find module 'randomhex' "

Tags: terminal, mocha.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm currently taking this udemy course on developing networks on Ethereum. The course was made two years ago so I sort of have to use old versions of everything to follow through. My code would run just fine when performing "npm run test" but after adding the statement in line 29 (the assert.ok statement), I started getting this error. I don't understand what is the terminal error. Help?

**inbox.test.js:**

```
//inbox.test.js
const assert = require('assert'); // used for ganache assertion
const ganache = require('ganache-cli'); // local ethereum testing netwrok 
const Web3 = require('web3'); // Web3 is a constructor function (that's why it is capatalized)
const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile'); // descructors - going up the directory tree 

 // creating an instance of Web3
const provider = ganache.provider();
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

let accounts; // to be accessed globally 
let inbox; // holds the deployed contract 

beforeEach( async () => {
// Get a list of all accounts 
accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts(); //eth is a module that has a lot of functions used for development 
   
// Use one of the accounts to deploy the contract 
inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract (JSON.parse(interface)) // instance of a contract
.deploy({data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi There!'] })
.send ({from: accounts[0], gas:'1000000'}); 

inbox.setProvider(provider); 

});

describe('Inbox', ()=> {
    it('deployes a contract', () => {
     assert.ok(inbox.options.address); // to check if the contract is successfuly depolyed 
    });

    it('has a default message', async () => {
      const message = await inbox.methods.message().call();
      assert.equal(message, 'Hi there!');
    });
    
    it('can change the message', async () => {
      await inbox.methods.setMessage('bye').send( {from: accounts[0]} );const message = await inbox.methods.message().call();
      assert.equal(message, 'bye'); 
    });


});
```

**Terminal error:**

[Terminal Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWCEY.png)

[Terminal Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzJju.png)

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "Eiman",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.9.1",
    "mocha": "^8.1.0",
    "solc": "^0.4.17",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"
  }
}
```

**compile.js:**

```
// Modules 
const path = require ('path'); // module used to help build a path from compile.js to inbox.sol - guaranteed to get compatibility with OS used  
const fs = require ('fs');
const solc = require ('solc'); 

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'inbox.sol' );
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8'); // to read the content of the inbox.sol file
module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Inbox']; // compile statement
```

**inbox.sol:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Inbox {

    string public message;



    function Inbox (string initalMessage) public {
        message = initalMessage;
    }




    function setMessage(string newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs smoothly on my Mac (the strings are actually different):

```
Inbox
    ✓ deployes a contract
    1) has a default message
    ✓ can change the message (74ms)


  2 passing (405ms)
  1 failing

  1) Inbox
       has a default message:

      AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 'Hi There!' == 'Hi there!'
      + expected - actual

      -Hi There!
      +Hi there!
```

Looks like some problem with your node_modules, try a fresh install.

Comment: I came back to the code today to ran the test again and it worked! I didn't make any changes to it and got the same results you got! Thank you for your help and I'll keep in mind your solution in case I come across the same problem again!